# Inflating views on listview item

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview. What I've implemented in that listview is that when user clicks a list item a 2 button view is inflated to replace the content of that list item like this:

[image]

This works fine but what I want is when I click the second list item the first one should come back to its original layout. Currently, it is like this:

[image]

This is my code implemented in onClick method of listview:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                TextView planName = view.findViewById(R.id.planNameText);
                TextView planDate = view.findViewById(R.id.planDateText);
                ImageView planImage = view.findViewById(R.id.homePlanImageView);
                planName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                planDate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                planImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                RelativeLayout rl_inflate = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.rl_inflate);
                View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflate, null);
                rl_inflate.addView(child);

        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: adding a swipe view to your listview will be better in my opinion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you need to initialice a **boolean** variable to check if is clicked or not and refresh all the views. I really recommend you to use a **RecyclerView** and use 2 **viewHolders**. If you want information about this check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type). If you implement a recycler with 2 viewholder it will be easier than the way that you want to implement it, and you can use **notifyDataSetChanged** to refresh the recycler. Whatever, you will need anyways a boolean to check if is clicked or not.

Comment: I'm implementing this in my activity so I might have to refresh the activity in my listview's setOnItemClickListener method. am I right?

Comment: Yes. You have to implement the notifyDataSetChanged on your activity. Its like adapter. notifyDataSetChanged();
This will refresh your listview with the new datas.
Also you have to clear() the adapter or just implement another.